# Trigger function on swipe

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement a way of triggering a function on a swipe in Flutter. I am building a UI with a stacked card layout using Flutter_Swiper (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)

I have tried using both GestureDetector and SwipeDetector (https://pub.dev/packages/swipedetector) but both of these result in Flutter_Swiper breaking.

Does anyone know of a way of using Flutter_Swiper to trigger a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can call function in `onIndexChanged` 
code snippet

```
return Swiper(
      onTap: (int index) {
        ...
      customLayoutOption: customLayoutOption,
      fade: _fade,
      index: _currentIndex,
      onIndexChanged: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = index;
          print(_currentIndex);
        });
      },
```

working demo

[image]

output

```
I/flutter ( 4664): 1
I/flutter ( 4664): 2
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_page_indicator/flutter_page_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class FormWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;

  final Widget child;

  FormWidget({this.label, this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(label, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
            Expanded(
                child: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: child))
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class FormSelect<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final String placeholder;
  final ValueChanged<T> valueChanged;
  final List<dynamic> values;
  final dynamic value;

  FormSelect({this.placeholder, this.valueChanged, this.value, this.values});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _FormSelectState();
  }
}

class _FormSelectState extends State<FormSelect> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0, c = widget.values.length; i < c; ++i) {
      if (widget.values[i] == widget.value) {
        _selectedIndex = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String placeholder = widget.placeholder;
    List<dynamic> values = widget.values;

    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Text(_selectedIndex < 0
            ? placeholder
            : values[_selectedIndex].toString()),
        onTap: () {
          _selectedIndex = 0;
          showBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: values.length * 30.0 + 200.0,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: values.length * 30.0 + 70.0,
                        child: CupertinoPicker(
                          itemExtent: 30.0,
                          children: values.map((dynamic value) {
                            return Text(value.toString());
                          }).toList(),
                          onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) {
                            _selectedIndex = index;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_selectedIndex >= 0) {
                              widget
                                  .valueChanged(widget.values[_selectedIndex]);
                            }

                            setState(() {});

                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text("ok"),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberPad extends StatelessWidget {
  final num number;
  final num step;
  final num max;
  final num min;
  final ValueChanged<num> onChangeValue;

  NumberPad({this.number, this.step, this.onChangeValue, this.max, this.min});

  void onAdd() {
    onChangeValue(number + step > max ? max : number + step);
  }

  void onSub() {
    onChangeValue(number - step < min ? min : number - step);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.exposure_neg_1), onPressed: onSub),
        Text(
          number is int ? number.toString() : number.toStringAsFixed(1),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
        ),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.exposure_plus_1), onPressed: onAdd)
      ],
    );
  }
}

const List<String> images = [
  "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
  "https://picsum.photos/250?image=10",
  "https://picsum.photos/250?image=11",
];

class ExampleCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ExampleCustomState();
  }
}

class _ExampleCustomState extends State<ExampleCustom> {
  //properties want to custom
  int _itemCount;

  bool _loop;

  bool _autoplay;

  int _autoplayDely;

  double _padding;

  bool _outer;

  double _radius;

  double _viewportFraction;

  SwiperLayout _layout;

  int _currentIndex;

  double _scale;

  Axis _scrollDirection;

  Curve _curve;

  double _fade;

  bool _autoplayDisableOnInteraction;

  CustomLayoutOption customLayoutOption;

  Widget _buildItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(_radius)),
      child: Image.network(
        images[index % images.length],
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ExampleCustom oldWidget) {
    customLayoutOption = CustomLayoutOption(startIndex: -1, stateCount: 3)
        .addRotate([-45.0 / 180, 0.0, 45.0 / 180]).addTranslate(
            [Offset(-370.0, -40.0), Offset(0.0, 0.0), Offset(370.0, -40.0)]);
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    customLayoutOption = CustomLayoutOption(startIndex: -1, stateCount: 3)
        .addRotate([-25.0 / 180, 0.0, 25.0 / 180]).addTranslate(
            [Offset(-350.0, 0.0), Offset(0.0, 0.0), Offset(350.0, 0.0)]);
    _fade = 1.0;
    _currentIndex = 0;
    _curve = Curves.ease;
    _scale = 0.8;
    _controller = SwiperController();
    _layout = SwiperLayout.TINDER;
    _radius = 10.0;
    _padding = 0.0;
    _loop = true;
    _itemCount = 3;
    _autoplay = false;
    _autoplayDely = 3000;
    _viewportFraction = 0.8;
    _outer = false;
    _scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal;
    _autoplayDisableOnInteraction = false;
    super.initState();
  }

// maintain the index

  Widget buildSwiper() {
    return Swiper(
      onTap: (int index) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(" page"),
            ),
            body: Container(),
          );
        }));
      },
      customLayoutOption: customLayoutOption,
      fade: _fade,
      index: _currentIndex,
      onIndexChanged: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = index;
          print(_currentIndex);
        });
      },
      curve: _curve,
      scale: _scale,
      itemWidth: 300.0,
      controller: _controller,
      layout: _layout,
      outer: _outer,
      itemHeight: 200.0,
      viewportFraction: _viewportFraction,
      autoplayDelay: _autoplayDely,
      loop: _loop,
      autoplay: _autoplay,
      itemBuilder: _buildItem,
      itemCount: _itemCount,
      scrollDirection: _scrollDirection,
      indicatorLayout: PageIndicatorLayout.COLOR,
      autoplayDisableOnInteraction: _autoplayDisableOnInteraction,
      pagination: SwiperPagination(
          builder: const DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
              size: 20.0, activeSize: 20.0, space: 10.0)),
    );
  }

  SwiperController _controller;
  TextEditingController numberController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: Colors.black87,
        child: SizedBox(
            height: 300.0, width: double.infinity, child: buildSwiper()),
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Index:$_currentIndex"),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _controller.previous(animation: true);
                },
                child: Text("Prev"),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _controller.next(animation: true);
                },
                child: Text("Next"),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                controller: numberController,
              )),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  var text = numberController.text;
                  setState(() {
                    _currentIndex = int.parse(text);
                  });
                },
                child: Text("Update"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          FormWidget(
              label: "layout",
              child: FormSelect(
                  placeholder: "Select layout",
                  value: _layout,
                  values: [
                    SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
                    SwiperLayout.STACK,
                    SwiperLayout.TINDER,
                    SwiperLayout.CUSTOM
                  ],
                  valueChanged: (value) {
                    _layout = value;
                    setState(() {});
                  })),
          FormWidget(
            label: "scrollDirection",
            child: Switch(
                value: _scrollDirection == Axis.horizontal,
                onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() => _scrollDirection =
                    value ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical)),
          ),
          FormWidget(
            label: "autoplayDisableOnInteractio",
            child: Switch(
                value: _autoplayDisableOnInteraction,
                onChanged: (bool value) =>
                    setState(() => _autoplayDisableOnInteraction = value)),
          ),
          //Pannel Begin
          FormWidget(
            label: "loop",
            child: Switch(
                value: _loop,
                onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() => _loop = value)),
          ),
          FormWidget(
            label: "outer",
            child: Switch(
                value: _outer,
                onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() => _outer = value)),
          ),
          //Pannel Begin
          FormWidget(
            label: "autoplay",
            child: Switch(
                value: _autoplay,
                onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() => _autoplay = value)),
          ),

          FormWidget(
            label: "padding",
            child: NumberPad(
              number: _padding,
              step: 5.0,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 30.0,
              onChangeValue: (num value) {
                _padding = value.toDouble();
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
          FormWidget(
            label: "scale",
            child: NumberPad(
              number: _scale,
              step: 0.1,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 1.0,
              onChangeValue: (num value) {
                _scale = value.toDouble();
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
          FormWidget(
            label: "fade",
            child: NumberPad(
              number: _fade,
              step: 0.1,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 1.0,
              onChangeValue: (num value) {
                _fade = value.toDouble();
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
          FormWidget(
            label: "itemCount",
            child: NumberPad(
              number: _itemCount,
              step: 1,
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              onChangeValue: (num value) {
                _itemCount = value.toInt();
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),

          FormWidget(
            label: "radius",
            child: NumberPad(
              number: _radius,
              step: 1.0,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 30.0,
              onChangeValue: (num value) {
                this._radius = value.toDouble();
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),

          FormWidget(
            label: "viewportFraction",
            child: NumberPad(
              number: _viewportFraction,
              step: 0.1,
              max: 1.0,
              min: 0.5,
              onChangeValue: (num value) {
                _viewportFraction = value.toDouble();
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),

          FormWidget(
              label: "curve",
              child: FormSelect(
                  placeholder: "Select curve",
                  value: _layout,
                  values: [
                    Curves.easeInOut,
                    Curves.ease,
                    Curves.bounceInOut,
                    Curves.bounceOut,
                    Curves.bounceIn,
                    Curves.fastOutSlowIn
                  ],
                  valueChanged: (value) {
                    _curve = value;
                    setState(() {});
                  })),
        ],
      ))
    ]);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: ExampleCustom()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats really useful!
Do you know a good way of working out if the user has swiped left or right using this?

Comment: you can check index number and keep previous no , 0 to 1 means swipe left, 1 to 0 means swipe right.